# Debt to asset ratio calculation

Tags: debt, balance-sheet, liability

When try to calculate `debt-to-asset ratio`, I came across different formulas. There are:

1. `Total debt divided by total asset`, where `Total debt = short-term debt + long-term debt` from Balance Sheet.
2. `Total liabilities divided by total asset`

In financial world, which is the more widely used formula here? As (2) will give a higher ratio than (1).

Answer (score 4):

One is not "better" than the other.  They measure different things. Debt is a measure of how a company is financed, and how solvent they are (how many assets they have that could be used to pay off debt).  Total liabilities include non-"debt" liabilities like receivables and long-term lease obligations, which are more on an operational measure (how much a company's sales are on credit).

So it's more important to choose the one that matches what you're trying to measure, but more important that that is to be *consistent* when comparing companies to each other.

Answer (score 2):

(If you're asking this in regards to your own situation... people have different needs from "the financial world". My answer is solely about personal finance.)

Compute **both** a `debt` ratio **and** a `liabilities` ratio.  Even break down the debt ration into `short-term debt divided by short-term assets` and `long-term debt divided by long-term assets`.

You can also compute your Quick Ratio, which is `short term assets divided by liabilities`.

Note that **in this context** I don't put monthly bills in the "liabilities" category.  Only "large", future (3-12 months away) expenditures go in that bucket.  Examples are: summer vacation, end of year property tax, semi-annual and annual insurance premiums, etc.